# SFML build all batch file

Tags: c++, batch-file, sfml

I was wondering if there was a way to alter the below code so it will build all the ".cpp" and ".h" files in a folder (+ subfolders) and specify one .exe name to be made.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Building...
g++ -DSFML_STATIC main.cpp -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s
```

I know I can use CMake, but I want to know if it's possible with a batch script. If I can't do what I'm asking, can I at least specify a name for the .exe? It always comes out as "a.exe". I am using MingW.

Sorry, if this has been covered already. I searched and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify the name for the output file, add option "-o name.exe".

To pass a large number of files to g++, you will have to use a response file like so:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%f in (*.cpp) do (
    set a=%%f
    set a=!a:\=/!
    echo !a! >>files.tmp
)
endlocal
g++ -DSFML_STATIC @files.tmp -o bob.exe -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s
del files.tmp
```

Note that you should only give the *.cpp files to g++. It will find the .h files on its own while compiling.

I don't have a MingW setup so I wasn't able to test this completely, sorry. But the part about building the response file works at least.

Sources:

[http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW_for_First_Time_Users_HOWTO]
[http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true]
[[Multiple do commands in a for loop: Echoing a string to a file and then redirecting to the command window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109897/multiple-do-commands-in-a-for-loop-echoing-a-string-to-a-file-and-then-redirect])

Comment: I get an error: g++ error: C:UsersCressDocumentsTestmain.cpp: No such file or directory. It is omitting the forward slashes for some reason.

I tried looking at your sources, but the commands on the Microsoft site made little sense to me. Sorry, I'm new to scripting.

Comment: @cress No worries, cmd.exe is not exactly user-friendly... I updated with code to turn backslashes into forward slashes. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 0):

"a.exe" is the default name that g++ uses for executables on Windows.  If you want to specify your own name, add "-o foo.exe" to the g++ command line.

Comment: Thanks! Home come a custom name loads the program slower? If I don't specify a name and run "a.exe", it loads a simple window in less than a second. If I add "-o main.exe", it takes 1-2 seconds to open up the program.

Comment: @cress: No idea why it would take longer to load.